# How to write a FOR loop in windows 95 command prompt?

Tags: for-loop, windows-95

I would like to write a simple script in win95 command prompt that enumerate integers and echo'es them. How can I write it?

Bonus question: is there a while loop available?

Pseudo code:

```
for i in (1,1,1000000) do echo i
```

It is surprisingly challenging since win95 is so old that I couldn't find any reliable info quickly.

Thanks

Comment: Your example isn't counting integers.  It would help to know the exact task but you will find `qbasic.exe` is the tool to use.

Comment: sorry, edited the question.

Comment: @foxidrive Why should he want to use QBasic? He explicitly asked about the command prompt. Concerning the question: Windows 95 is not different to DOS in that respect, so you might want to have a look at the first Google match I came up with about FOR loops in DOS: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/for.php

Comment: I actually tried the following command which resulted in a syntax error:
`FOR /L %i in (1,1,10000) DO ECHO %i`

Comment: I'd also like to know why the downvote on the question?

Comment: @qqilihq Win95 has no native calculation routines, apart from labourious techniques which are not mathematical in nature.  Using `Qbasic` was the most common method back then.  I asked the OP for more details so I could provide a native solution, if possible, but they aren't forthcoming.

Comment: The exact task is actually echoing integers in sequence on a cmd terminal in win95.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using MSDOS6/WIN9x techniques.

```
@echo off
:loop
echo z>>tmp.tmp
find /c "z" <tmp.tmp
goto :loop
```